# Windows 8 very long delay after incorrect password entered

Tags: windows-8, passwords

I have a Windows 8 Pro x64 installation, and whenever I mistype my password the login process just hangs around for 3-4 minutes. The circular progress dots continue to swirl around, but there doesn't seem to be a way to persuade the screen to revert to a state where I can type the correct password before that timeout expires.

I normally know straight away that I've typed the incorrect password - so it's quicker to reset my machine - but that doesn't seem right given that it's not 1996 any more.

Are there any ways to find out why it takes so long?

Comment: use xbootmgr to see what is slow: http://www.msfn.org/board/index.php?showtopic=158252

Comment: Is the PC domain-joined? Are you using an MS account or a local account?

Comment: The PC isn't in a domain and it's an MS account...

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/979975/windows-delays-login-after-a-couple-failed-attempts?answertab=active#tab-top.... should answer your question

Comment: @Prasanna - it doesn't, this happens after the first attempt.